# UWP, loading csv file with correct encoding

Tags: c#, uwp, filepicker

When I want to load a csv file that includes letter "ş", "ü", it gives me �.

my codes are like below;

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file!=null)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file.Path);
            for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count(); i++)
            {
                data2 = lines[i].Split(';');
```

As far as I found on internet, I need to use iso-8859-9 encoding but I dont know how to apply to my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an encoding problem. `File.ReadAllLines`  uses *UTF-8* by default. Below code should work

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file.Path,  Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1254"));
```

PS: You may also try with `ISO-8859-9` instead of `Windows-1254`

Comment: I tried "Windows-1254" and  "ISO-8859-9" but it gave me this error
"is not a supported encoding name."

Comment: What about Windows-28599 (from Wikipedia)